# Генерация POST запроса с php curl в JSON формате

Tags: php, json, api, http, curl

пытаюсь получить токен для api digiseller
https://my.digiseller.com/inside/api_general.asp#token 
Пытаюсь сформировать вот такой запрос, но выдает ошибку с кодом "-1", где сказано "Неверный идентификатор продавца или подпись!"

```
$seller = '123456';
$ID = 'ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF';
$timestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$sign = hash('sha256', $ID . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);

$data = array(
    'id_seller' => $seller,
    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
    'sign' => $sign
    );

$payload = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.digiseller.ru/api/apilogin");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json"
  ));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $server_output;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, перепутал местами id_seller и seller_id xD

Comment: дай ответ на свой вопрос для сообщества